# Is there any other alternative to jlink and jrecreate for making custom jre?

Tags: java

I want a list of some alternatives to `jlink` and `jrecreate`. The problem is that I don't want to use `jdk 9` and I am on a windows machine so I cannot use `jrecreate`.